# Java import или пути?

Tags: java

Есть переменная (values) в class1 (package1), нужно ее импортировать в class2(package2).

Есть 2 способа:

```
package package2;
import package1.class1;
```

или же обратиться на прямую к переменной

```
package package2;
package1.class1.values...
```

Какой способ буде быстрее в плане производительности?

P.S. Удобство использования не волнует!

Comment: Одинаково. Может прямое обращение на долю секунды быстрее скомпилируется.

Answer (score 7):

На скорость выполнения программы не повлияет, потому что компилятор все-равно заменит название переменных на полные пути.
Например,

```
package aug;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        out.println("abc");
    }
}
```

Если посмотреть декомпилятором:

```
package aug;

public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
}
```

Часть байткода:

```
 public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 7 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    LDC "abc"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 8 L1
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```